# Getting average per day using the extract and last_day functions

Tags: sql, oracle11g

need a quick help here
I have this small project, I have this report that have the total of order along with the date of the order (This a continuation from my other question actually)
So here's what I've been doing

```
SELECT  sf.ORDER_QNT, dd.ACTUAL_DATE, dd.MONTH_NUMBER
FROM    sales_fact sf,
        date_dim dd
WHERE   dd.date_id = sf.date_id
AND dd.MONTH_NUMBER = 1;

 ORDER_QNT          ACTUAL_DATE MONTH_NUMBER
 -------------------------------------------
      1100             05/01/13            1
       100             05/01/13            1
       140             06/01/13            1
       110             07/01/13            1
       200             08/01/13            1
       500             08/01/13            1
       230             08/01/13            1
       500             08/01/13            1
       200             08/01/13            1
        53             15/01/13            1
        53             22/01/13            1
```

Now, I want to get the average for that month (average per day) by using the last_day function.

```
SELECT  sum(sf.ORDER_QNT)/EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(to_date('05/01/13','dd/mm/rr'))) as AVGPERDAY,
        dd.month_number
FROM    sales_fact sf,
        date_dim dd
WHERE   dd.date_id = sf.date_id
AND     dd.month_number = 1
GROUP BY dd.month_number;

AVGPERDAY    MONTH_NUMBER
--------------------------
113.785714        1
```

The result is nice, but now when I change the date with the dd.actual_date it gives error

```
SELECT  sum(sf.ORDER_QNT)/EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(dd.actual_date)) as AVGPERDAY,
        dd.month_number
FROM    sales_fact sf,
        date_dim dd
WHERE   dd.date_id = sf.date_id
AND     dd.month_number = 1
GROUP BY dd.month_number;


Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 53
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum(sf.ORDER_QNT) / decode(round(max(dd.actual_date) - min(dd.actual_date)), 0, 1)
```

You may use this expression in your query (but the result may be not the same as with LAST_DAY)

Or you may make EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(dd.actual_date)) the part of a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT  sum(sf.ORDER_QNT)/EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(dd.actual_date)) as AVGPERDAY,
        dd.month_number
FROM    sales_fact sf,
        date_dim dd
WHERE   dd.date_id = sf.date_id
AND     dd.month_number = 1
GROUP BY dd.month_number, EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(dd.actual_date));
```